# Formatting a Picker (color and font size)

Tags: swiftui, picker

This has to be one of the most NOOB questions. I would like to change the foreground, background colors and the font size of a Picker

Xcode
Version 14.2 (14C18)

macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let numberOfIntervals = [
        "1 Interval",
        "2 Intervals",
        "3 Intervals",
        "4 Intervals"
    ]  
    @State var selectedInterval: String = "1"

    var body: some View {
            Picker ("Choose an Interval", selection: $selectedInterval) {
                ForEach (numberOfIntervals, id: \.self) { intervals in
                    Text (intervals)
                        .font(.largeTitle) // this does not change anything
                }
                .padding()
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this for macOS?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `Text` with modifiers in a separate view

```
struct PickerRow: View {
    let text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .font(.headline)
            .italic()
    }
}
```

And use it with your picker code

```
Picker ("Choose an Interval", selection: $selectedInterval) {
    ForEach (numberOfIntervals, id: \.self) { intervals in
         PickerRow(text: intervals)
    }
}
```

*this solution was tested and verified on macOS*

Comment: Works in macOS as requested, but apparently not in iOS.

Comment: @TimNewton Thanks for the info, I only tested for macOS since that was what mentioned in the question but now I wonder if OP meant it that way since they didn’t found my answer useful.